# Which scenario is more efficient?

Tags: c++, database

ALL,
I have a DB with some data.
I also have a C++ application that communicates with the DB.

Which scenario is more efficient?

Scenario 1:

1. User hit "Edit Data" button.
2. Program reads data from DB and presents it for editing
3. User edit the data and hit "Save" button
4. Program creates new object with the newly saved data then makes the comparison with the old object.
5. Program issues some UPDATE statements.

Scenario 2:

1. Steps 1-3 are the same.
2. Program overwrites an old object data with the new data.
3. Program issue DELETE/INSERT statements in one transaction.

I'm inclined to say scenario 2.

Comment: I'm inclined to say option 1. But there is no general answer, there are so many variables in your question. The only way to get an answer is to try both methods and **time it**.

Comment: @john, You talking from the DB perspective, right? What about C++ point of view? There are some strings, integers and vectors.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "more efficient"? Faster? Uses less memory? Uses less other resources? The only way to truly know which is more "efficient" is to measure! Try both ways, and measure whatever thing you consider important, and then you will know for certain.

Comment: @Igor I'd be surprised if the overall efficiency wasn't dominated by the database operations. But again timing is the only way to find out. Another consideration is what stackmonster said, update statements are designed for what you are doing. If you go with option two then some later programmer is going to say 'WTF, why did they do that?' And then start looking for reasons why. In other words keep it simple unless you have clear evidence that there's a benefit with the more complex, non-obvious route.

Answer (score 1):

Its a question of which is efficient and transactionally sound.  Deleting an existing object to perform an update is not transactionally sound.  Updates exist to update existing entities in the database.  If you are using synthetic keys you cant use this approach at all.

In most system, a refetch (to at least check if the object your about to commit has been modified since you requested it from the database) is mandatory.

Step 4 should read, refetch the object from the database to ensure it hasnt changed, then commit update or rollback.

Comment: stackmonster, user will be able not just change, but remove some data or add new. It's complicated transaction and I wanted to be on the safe side with deletion/insertion. This is not a "brand new" record creation and it's not record removal. It is possible to do all 3 operations here. And the data is stored mostly in vectors.

Comment: So a second user has a reference to the same data, you delete it, then the other user comes back to update it.  But its not there.  Just because it seems complicated doesnt mean you can take a pass on performing the transaction properly.